# EC2 instace setup with RDS

Tags: apache2, php, phpmyadmin, amazon-ec2

i have created and EC2 instance and select Ubuntu 16.04. Then setup a RDS instance. 
i have also installed phpmyadmin on EC2 and that is working fine with localhost and  credential i have provided. 
then i have added the "endpoint" in config.inc.php file. 
When i change host in phpmyadmin. it deny the access for RDS instance with same credentials. 
i have already try to uninstall and then reinstall myqsl server but no success.
How can i setup username and password for RDS host?

I am quite new to AWS so kindly help me to sort this out. thanks